# How can i make a call without showing dialer activity to particular number in android?

Tags: android, android-intent

How can I make a call without taking user to dialer activity. Is there any way to do it?
I have a requirement where i have to implement it auto without user interaction.
I have below code which is taking me to dialer that i have to avoid.

```
Intent callIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL);
callIntent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:123456789"));
startActivity(callIntent);
```

Comment: I'm really curious about your requirement, and the app you are building. Could you tell more?

Answer (score 1):

try like this.

```
Intent callIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL_BUTTON);
callIntent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:123456789"));
startActivity(callIntent);
```

i.e use ACTION_CALL_BUTTON insted of ACTION_CALL

Comment: and dont forget to add permission for it: `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE" />`

Comment: Thanks Budius,
I tried as you said but it's not working for me.